# How to run a python file in command promt when a button is clicked is on a webpage

Tags: python, html, django, button, cmd

I am trying to make a local webpage which later on will be deployed, in which when a button on the html webpage is clicked, it opens up a commend prompt window and run the program. I have tried to implement it this using django framework. I have added the python file to the project library for it to be accessible, I have implemented it in the following way in views.py file,

```
def beast(request):

out = run(sys.executable, ['beast.py'], shell=True)

return render(request,'page2.html')
```

No input is to be given to the python file. It compiles and runs, but when the button is clicked it gives out a `TypeError - bufsize must be an integer`

Please let me know what can be done for it to work

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define a function inside the beast.py which contains the code you have to run like this

beast.py

```
def beast_func():
  //your code....
  ...............
```

and import that function in views.py

```
from .beast import beast_func
```

then call the function

```
def beast_view(request):
    beast_func()
```

Comment: I have tried this and the, from .beast import beast_func, throws an error, and I also tried to run it by importing beast, but that throws an error that the beast_func() is not defined

Comment: make sure that beast file is inside the app folder.and also try with  - "from appname.beast import beast_func". also explain the error please

Comment: I have created a folder app and put the beast file in it, it throws me an error NameError at /beast, and a description of -  name 'beast' is not defined

Comment: no no you should put the beast.py in your django app folder where your view  is . And import the function from that beast.py file to the view

Comment: I did that too, it still shows the same error as before